# TCP sender android

Tags: java, android, tcp

Please tell me an simple example of sending a message protocol tcp from android. How to implement the method of Sand (ipServer,Port);

Comment: It's not the world's best question, but it actually is a real question with a real answer that has been provided.  Closing it as redundant to something else would have been far more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

```
String host = ...; // The host name can either be a machine name, such as "java.sun.com", or a textual representation of its IP address
int port = ...;
Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(host), port);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true); // true for auto flush
```

Now, you can send a message through the writer, something like:

```
writer.println("Hello World");
```

and you can read the incoming data through the reader, something like:

```
String incoming = reader.readLine();
```

Comment: Note that this must not be done on the UI thread however.

Answer (score 0):

There is large number of articles on topic you are asking on the net.  One of them is: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/simple-connection-example-part-ii-tcp-communication

Kind regards,
Bo